# Network down: Card not present on Slot(1)

Tags: linux, net

My netcard stopped working. This then started spamming into the log:

```
pciehp 0000:00:1c.5:pcie04: Card not present on Slot(1)
pciehp 0000:00:1c.5:pcie04: Card present on Slot(1)
```

How do I get the netcard working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suspend-to-disk solved this. Probably because it resat the card.